# Python Selenium 'module' object is not callable in python selenium script

Tags: python, selenium

Learning Selenium driven by Python and in my practice I keep getting the following error. I am stuck and could use some guidance

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "test_login.py", line 14, in
>   test_Login
>       loginpage = homePage(self.driver) TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

Here is my code

> test_login.py

```
import unittest
import homePage
from selenium import webdriver

class Login(unittest.TestCase):

  def setUp(self):
     self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
     self.driver.get("https://hub.docker.com/login/")

  def test_Login(self):
      loginpage = homePage(self.driver)
      loginpage.login(email,password)

  def tearDown(self):
      self.driver.close()

if __name__ == '__main__': unittest.main()
```

> homePage.py

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

class BasePage(object):

    def __init__(self, driver):
        self.driver = drive


class LoginPage(BasePage):
    locator_dictionary = {
        "userID": (By.XPATH, '//input[@placeholder="Username"]'),
        "passWord": (By.XPATH, '//input[@placeholder="Password"]'),
        "submittButton": (By.XPATH, '//button[text()="Log In"]'),
    }



    def set_userID(self, id):
        userIdElement = self.driver.find_element(*LoginPage.userID)
        userIdElement.send_keys(id)

    def login_error_displayed(self):
        notifcationElement = self.driver.find_element(*LoginPage.loginError)
        return notifcationElement.is_displayed()

    def set_password(self, password):
        pwordElement = self.driver.find_element(*LoginPage.passWord)
        pwordElement.send_keys(password)        

    def click_submit(self):
        submitBttn = self.driver.find_element(*LoginPage.submitButton)
        submitBttn.click()

    def login(self, id, password):
        self.set_password(password)
        self.set_email(id)
        self.click_submit()
```

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1):

I think here:

```
loginpage = homePage(self.driver)
```

you meant to instantiate the `LoginPage` class:

```
loginpage = homePage.LoginPage(self.driver)
```

Comment: Thank you for your fast respose.

Comment: Now I am getting: 

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_login.py", line 16, in test_Login
    loginpage.login('ID','PW')
  File "homePage.py", line 31, in login
    self.set_userID(id)
  File "/homePage.py", line 18, in set_userID
    userIdElement = self.driver.find_element(*LoginPage.userID)
AttributeError: type object 'LoginPage' has no attribute 'userID'

Where should I focus or look for this error's cause?  Thanks

Comment: @user1279586 you have a typo - see drive vs driver.

Comment: Not seeing it. again, still learning, do can you point me to the line for referncing and research?